# replace specific values vba

Tags: vba, excel, import

I'm a newbie in excel vba I'm in a internship for my school and my time here is almost ending and I need to do this or I fail I'm dealing with something that I don't know nothing and don't have enough time to learn without further ado I will explain,  my problem is to create and add to my existing piece of code that was made by the help of people from various excel forums and what the code needs to do is:

The main file imports weekly information form a certain files, and imagine it copies the values present in those columns to my main file and in another week file the same information is there but with some different changes. You can noticed the changes by the column "M" I will explain what are the changes in the information that is imported it's  496 it's in trial when it is good to go it changes it status to 800 and it's ready to be implemented so I need it when detects a specific value that was 496 now in 800 to change the line where it is in to the other value of the other file like so:

value from week 12: addf asdafd asds 496

value from week 24: addf asdafd asds 800

The values that are in the SourceWb.Sheets(1) are always 496 and in the SourceWb.Sheets(2) always 800, the values that are present in SourceWb.Sheets(1) eventually will pass to the SourceWb.Sheets(2) and then I need to replace the file that is present in the main file that is 496 for the 800 one, when they pass from 496 to 800 it always occurs in another file like in week 12 file is 496 in SourceWb.Sheets(1) and then imagine in week 20 file it's in the SourceWb.Sheets(2)  and it's 800. So what I need to do is to then when importing replace the line where the information from week 12 SourceWb.Sheets(1)  and 496 to the one from SourceWb.Sheets(2). It probably is simple but I cannot do it, If more information is needed just say it.

The 
here is the code:

```
Sub ImportData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Path As String, Lstrw As Long
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim TargetWb As Workbook

Path = "C:\Users\DZPH8SH\Desktop\Status 496 800 semana 12 2015.xls"    'Change this to your company workbook path
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Path)
Set TargetWb = ThisWorkbook

Dim n As Integer, targetRow As Long
targetRow = 3

With SourceWb.Sheets(1)
Lstrw = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
.Range("M1:M" & Lstrw).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="496"
.Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw), .Range("N2:N" & Lstrw)).Copy
TargetWb.Sheets(7).Cells(TargetWb.Sheets(7).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.ShowAllData
End With

With SourceWb.Sheets(2)
Lstrw = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
.Application.Union(.Range("D2:D" & Lstrw), .Range("F2:F" & Lstrw), .Range("I2:I" & Lstrw), .Range("M2:M" & Lstrw), .Range("N2:N" & Lstrw)).Copy
TargetWb.Sheets(7).Cells(TargetWb.Sheets(7).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

SourceWb.Close savechanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

thanks for any reply in advance.

Comment: Isn't the point of an internship to learn the skills that the internship is about? "I don't have time to learn, please do it for me" doesn't seem to be a good strategy for doing well.

Comment: I already stated to my boss that I didn't new such lvl of programming but He just wants it done, no matter what the resources I use like I said my internship is almost ending and don't have time to learn the lvl of programming that is being demanded.

Comment: I tried doing it without success you cannot judge people without knowing any of the information regarding the time the other person as or the skill.

Comment: Maybe there are some extenuating circumstances in your case, but you come across as someone who wants others to do their homework for them. From your profile it seems like you have been doing this project for at least 40 days. How long does it take to read a book?

Comment: At the internship I did at the beginning of the year I had to learn VBA to assist our accountant in automating quite a few daily tasks. I was able to learn enough to complete the projects in a matter of a week or so. Just research. It's amazing what is already on this site that you can apply to your problem. I'd suggest taking a look around and finding pieces that apply to you, try them, and when you run into issues then post the problem and then we can help in a more efficient manner.

Comment: that's the problem got probably 3 days to make this did everything else, but this and my internship is about 1 month and is almost ending (next week).

Comment: Just so I am understanding this. You want the row with 496 to become 800 when the file is being imported?

Comment: yes that's correct the 496 present in some line would be replaced by the 800.     For example: V12rg 496 and then it becomes 800 in another week and then it should paste overit as 800 and the different information from the fields as well

Comment: Will there be any gaps in data? For example: the row that has 496 will always have 496 and not be empty? Also will the placement of the numbers be the same all the time? For example: 496 will always be in row G (or whatever row it is placed in)

Comment: cannot understand will try to explain somehting, this values are all imported to the main file and they will be always on the columns that are stated above in the source file never changing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is this. I have it commented so you can tell what each part does. Just take the guts (everything inside the sub) and paste it into your current code edit the section about what row to search through and then it should work just fine.

**NOTE**

Place this code after the code that transfers the data from SourceWb.Sheets(1) to SourceWb.Sheets(2).

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Chng As Range

'activate worksheet  
Worksheets("SourceWb.Sheets(2)").Activate

'Searches for the last row that is populated in SourceWb.Sheets(2). Change all "A" to whatever row you need
For Each Chng In Range("A1:A" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)

'This changes the value to 800 as long as the cell = 496. If it <> 496 then the cell will not be changed. 
If UCase(Chng) = "496" Then Chng = "800"

'Gets the next cell
Next Chng
End Sub
```